# Join post detail to like query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table's called posts and likes.

I'm trying to get all current users (logged-in user) likes + detail of the target post that is liked by the user.

*post_id* in likes table have relation to posts table id.

What is correct query ?

```
SELECT post.id,post.author,post.title,post.body,post.image,post.created_date
FROM posts post, likes like
WHERE like.user_id = :user_id;
                        "
```

likes table columns = *user_id, post_id,*

post table columns = *id, title, body, image, created_date*

Comment: Like is a reserved word and you aren't gaining much by dropping 1 letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an explicit condition for your `JOIN`. Also note that `,` join syntax has been outdated for a long time and you really should use explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT p.id, p.author, p.title, p.body, p.image, p.created_date
FROM posts p
JOIN likes l ON l.post_id = p.id
WHERE l.user_id = :user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Part of your issue with your query is that there are reserved key words in SQL queries, **LIKE** is one of them as well as SELECT, VALUE, WHERE IN, ON IF.

[Full list of reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)

When a column name or a reference conflicts with with a reserved word you have to wrap it in an acute emphasis (`) so that it is not parsed as a condition.

> `  -- Acute, Back quote, grave, grave accent, left quote, open quote, or a push

```
SELECT post.id,post.author,post.title,post.body,post.image,post.created_date
FROM posts post, likes `like`
WHERE `like`.user_id = :user_id;
```

Personally I always encase all my columns and references just to be sure and use full verbose queries:

```
SELECT `post`.`id`, `post`.`author`, `post`.`title`, `post`.`body`, `post`.`image`, `post`.`created_date`
FROM `posts` AS `post`, `likes` AS `like`
WHERE `like`.`user_id` = :user_id;
```

To get your query working you should use a `LEFT JOIN` on `likes`, Left join will ensure you get your post data even if there are no like records to select, You should get the likes for the post and where the post matches the user id not the like.

```
SELECT `post`.`id`, `post`.`author`, `post`.`title`, `post`.`body`, `post`.`image`, `post`.`created_date`
FROM `posts` AS `post`
LEFT JOIN `likes` AS `like` ON `like`.`post_id` = `post`.`id`
WHERE `post`.`user_id` = :user_id;
```